# Overriding compareTo at Enums

Tags: java, class, sorting, methods, enums

I want to sort this Enum as **reversed alphabetical order** and return it. When I try to use compareTo method by overriding it I saw that it is declared as **final**.

Is there a way to override Enum similar with compareTo

How is it possible to sort this so I get:

> D,C,B,A

```
public enum Test { 
 C(1)
 B(2)
 A(3)
 D(4)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The `Enum` implementation of `compareTo()` is based on the enum's `ordinal` value.

The `ordinal` is:

- A primitive `final int` value
- Assigned during construction
- Based on the order of enum declaration
- Starting at `0` (zero)

---

So, if you would like the enum to sort in a different order, you can simply declare them in that order:

```
public enum Test { D(4), C(1), B(2), A(3) }
```

(not sure what the values you pass to the constructor represent, so I maintained your values)

Comment: This is the correct answer IMO, given that Java doesn't allow you to override `compareTo` directly.  The only trouble is that if your IDE auto-sorts the enum then it will ruin your work. ;)   It's kind of annoying that Java does not allow you to override `compareTo` in the first place...

Answer (score 0):

Since you can't implement the `java.lang.Comparable` on `enum`, one way is to create a wrapper `java.util.Set` to compare the `enum` on the name.

```java
Set<Test> testEnumSet = new TreeSet<>(new Comparator<Test>() {
   @Override
   public int compare(Test first, Test second) {
      return second.name().compareTo(first.name());
   }
});

testEnumSet.addAll(Arrays.asList(Test.values()));
```

This will produce the sort

```
[D, C, B, A]
```

To change the order to ascending:

```java
return -(second.name().compareTo(first.name()));
```